# Transclude removes tr and td tags?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following angularjs application, but for some reason the tr and td tags are removed?

```js
angular.module('transcludeExample', [])
  .directive('pane', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        title: '@'
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<table><tbody ng-transclude></tbody></table>'
    };
  })
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {}]);
```

```css
td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  pre
  <pane>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>testtest</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </pane>
  post
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that browser ignores this html code, because `<table>` tag is initially missing(so it displays only the text):

```
 <tr>
  <td><strong>testtest</strong></td>
</tr>
```

I think the only solution is to move `ng-transclude` to outer element and not split table tags. For example : [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/p0txkns8/5/)